# Retrieve column names of a table into a combo box

Tags: c#, sql-server

Im using c# windows form application. I have a database with many tables. Each table has several columns. I need to populate the combo box with the column names for a selected table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of doing this on SQL Server 2005 and up (you didn't specify quite clearly what version you're using) would be to inspect the system catalog view, which live in the `sys` schema:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM    
    sys.columns
WHERE
    object_id = object_id('YourTableNameHere')
ORDER BY
    name
```

The `sys.columns` catalog view gives you quite a bit of information about the columns for a table - the table is identified by the `object_id` column, which is the internal ID for that table in question.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the list of tables

```
SELECT name 
FROM dbo.sysobjects 
WHERE xtype = 'U'
```

And this should give you column information per table

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'
```

Comment: "sysobjects" is deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 - please start using "sys.objects" and the other catalog views in the "sys" schema

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can query the column names from sql server.  Other databases are similar to this. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/05/sql-server-2005-get-field-name-and-type-of-database-table/

As far as getting the items into a combobox you can find volumes of information on this on msdn at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983551(VS.71).aspx

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
string  sqlquery="select column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'student' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION";
     DataFind.Open();
     cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, DataFind);

     SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (DR.Read())
     {
         comboBox1.Items.Add(DR[0]);

     }
     DataFind.Close();
```